# I fail to execute hide & show jquery. what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

At first all element is hided, but when btn is clicked, I espect it show these:
[image]

Unfortunately, every time I click the button its show in a millisecond only then hide again.

This is the code
HTML:

```
<div id="datetimepicker"></div>
<div id="datetimepicker2"></div>

<input id="saveEdit" type="submit" name="updateDetail" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Save"></input>
<input id="cancelEdit" type="reset" name="cancelEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" value="Cancel"></input>
<input id="editYear" type="submit" name="editYear" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Edit"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
$('div#datetimepicker').hide();
$('div#datetimepicker2').hide();
$('input#cancelEdit').hide();
$('input#saveEdit').hide();

$(function() {
  $("#editYear").click(function() {
    $('div#datetimepicker').show();
    $('div#datetimepicker2').show();
    $('input#cancelEdit').show();
    $('input#saveEdit').show();
    $('input#editYear').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your problem?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal hmmm there are a lot elements (mysql, external libraries) in my code. I think it is difficult to create fiddle :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the calendars will auto-close when they detect a click outside.

Although you show them, they capture the "click outside" and close after that.

You can try 2 things:

- Add a timeout when you show the calendars, so it occurs after the default "hide".
- Add the calendars in another wrapper div, and try to manipulate the parent instead. And, you should check the calendar configuration to see if it hides automatically

.

```
$("#editYear").click(function() { 
    $('input#cancelEdit').show();
    $('input#saveEdit').show();
    $('input#editYear').hide();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('div#datetimepicker').show();
        $('div#datetimepicker2').show();
    }, 250);
});
```

Comment: Change 250 to 2000 just to be sure. Add a console.log as well

Comment: It is solved. The problem is because the input type is type="submit", it works when I changed it to "reset". Thank you anyway for your help... really Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a plugin for this?

If you did it's likely a bit of HTML is out of place or double datepickers isn't a supported feature of that plugin and the datepickers are detecting a click outside of their container.

First check the documentation from the right markup if there's no example of the implementation you are using then you will need to modify the method that closes the datepickers.

put some logs into the datepickers hide method to see what needs modifying. It would help you havea jsfiddle with your issue and know what plugin is being used.